# Input channel on audio mixer

Tags: mixing

I wonder if I could use the line level Stereo input left channel to plug an electric guitar, and the right channel for another guitar (having more channels available)? I understand that these line level input usually around 0.7-1.? volt, so if I have two hot signal sharing the same channel, will cause damage to the mixer or not ?

Comment: Are you using a DI box? Generally speaking, it is usually ok to use the L or R channel of a mixer, as long as no stereo processing is done in the mixer.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand what are you trying to achieve here. Are you plugging your electric guitar directly to mixer line input? In such case you won't be able to use the preamp to get any decent volume. You should be using a DI box and plug your guitar to the mic input on the mixer.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to connect two electric guitar , one to the left and one to the right of one channel, but I am afraid that it will overheat cause two hot signals going into one channel.

Comment: It will not cause an overhead and it will not sound good on it's own either - as Eugene mentioned the preamp will not be available so you a DI box or other sorts of pre-amplification before inputting the mixer.